# CSS3 Transition support in IE11+

Tags: css, animation

I've a simple CSS background-size transition animation, that's working fine in Chrome, Safari and Firefox. However in IE 11+ the transition doesn't work. It just zooms from the 100% to 110%. My CSS is as follows;

```
.hero {
 background-size: 100%;
 transition: all .9s ease;
 
 &:hover {
 background-size: 105%;
 }
}
```

However elsewhere on my site I use transform with transition and this works fine in IE.

```
.image {
display: block;
transition: all .9s ease;

&:hover {
transform: scale(1.1)
}
}
```

The only reason I don't use the second method, is because other elements would be effect by a transform and I only want the background image to adjust by size.

Comment: If you really think this _needs_ fixing (Who uses IE any more? And if they do, they should probably be used to getting less “optical candy” by now.), then you could place the background image into pseudo element absolutely positioned behind the element content, and then use your second method on that pseudo element only.

Comment: @CBroe - cheers dude, let me try this.